# For setting locale in Ubuntu, what does the LANGUAGE environment variable mean?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, localization

For setting locale in Ubuntu, what does the `LANGUAGE` environment variable mean?

It is not defined in [Ubuntu Community Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale/) or on [`man 1 locale`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/locale.1.html).

Related question: [In Ubuntu, what is the difference between en_US:utf8 and en_US: when setting LANGUAGE](https://serverfault.com/questions/455922/in-ubuntu-what-is-the-difference-between-en-usutf8-and-en-us-when-setting-lan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LANG` environment variable determines the language in which software programs communicate with the user.

More details are here: [Ubuntu Wiki - Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

For Language, Not all programs have translations for all languages. By default, an English message is shown in place of a nonexistent translation. If you understand other languages, you can set up a priority list of languages. This is done through a different environment variable, called `LANGUAGE`. GNU gettext gives preference to `LANGUAGE` over `LC_ALL` and `LANG` for the purpose of message handling, but you still need to have `LANG` (or `LC_ALL`) set to the primary language; This is required by other parts of the system libraries. For example, some Swedish users who would rather read translations in German than English for when Swedish is not available, set `LANGUAGE=sv:de` while leaving `LANG=sv_SE`.

More details can be found here: [GNU gettext manual - The LANGUAGE variable](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable)

Comment: but what about the variable `LANGUAGE` ? typing `locale` shows an entry for `LANGUAGE` as well.

Comment: Updated my answer .. please check.

Comment: thanks :-) accepted the answer. one more thing. on my server `LANG=en_US.utf8` and `LANGUAGE=en_US:` what is the difference if i set `LANGUAGE=en_US:utf8` ?