# in Ubuntu, what is the difference between en_US:utf8 and en_US: when setting LANGUAGE

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, localization

related question: [For setting locale in Ubuntu, what does the LANGUAGE environment variable mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/455718/for-setting-locale-in-ubuntu-what-does-the-language-environment-variable-mean)

for setting [locale](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale/) my existing Ubuntu 12.04 server has `LANGUAGE` as `en_US:`
And I can set it to `en_US:utf8` as well. What is the difference ?

existing configuration is, which i found by typing `locale`

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

EDIT: right now `LANGUAGE` is `en_US:`. notice the colon at the end

Answer (score 2):

`en_US` uses ASCII encoding, and `en_US.utf8` uses UTF8 (Unicode) encoding.  Since UTF8 is a superset of ASCII, it's the default, and a good choice unless you have a specific reason to avoid Unicode.

Comment: is `en_US:` the same as `en_US`? The first one has colon at the end

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, the colon has no significance.